# append a float at the end of array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to append a float at the end of the array in C. Here is the code used by me:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float timestamps[] = {0,3,2,1,5};
    float ISI[25];
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++ )
    {
      for (j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
          float diffTimestamp = timestamps[j] - timestamps[i];
          //remove points greater than 1 sec and less than -1sec
          if((diffTimestamp<=1.0)&&(diffTimestamp>=-1.0)){
              //append the diffTimestamp to ISI array 
          }
          else
            continue;
        }
   }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried googling it and came across a couple of similar questions:
[Appending a value to the end of a dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654041/appending-a-value-to-the-end-of-a-dynamic-array?rq=1). Another thing which was common was using a structure to put a variable for size along with the array.

But because of my limited knowledge of C, I am unable to implement the code.

Comment: *//append the diffTimestamp to ISI array*, where is the `ISI` array? It is just a pointer with value `NULL`.

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: You could use `fabs()` to simplify the condition: `if (fabs(diffTimeStamp) <= 1.0)`.  You simply need to keep an index for the next slot in the `ISI` array, or equivalently the number of entries in the array at the moment: `int count = 0;`.  You add an entry with `ISI[count++] = diffTimeStamp;`.

Comment: @deathracer `float ISI[25]` declares an *array of float [25 elements]*. This is created with a *Fixed* size and cannot be `realloc`ated. If you want to dynamically add to an array, you are actually just sizing the block of memory pointed to by a pointer variable. You can initially size a block of memory to hold `25-float` with something like `size_t size = 25; float *array = malloc (size * sizeof *array);` (don't forget to validate the allocation). Keep track of the number of floats added, and when 25 is reached `void *tmp = realloc (array, size * 2 * sizeof *array); if (tmp) array = tmp;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you initialize the array:

```
float timestamps[] = {0,3,2,1,5};
```

what you're doing is actually allocating a memory block that is exactly that size. Unlike a scripting language an array in this case is not a data type, instead it is a block of memory that has 5 floats saved contiguously.

What should be done is you should use a [linked list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html) which would allow you to implement what you're trying here.

Edit: you could also use malloc if you know how large the amount of memory you will need is.

Comment: `ISI` in worst case can be double the size of `timestamps` array ie. 25

Comment: Just declare the maximum size of ISI and keep a counter of the position that you last wrote to.

Comment: array __is__ a data type. The problem is you can't go over it's bounds

Comment: @deathracer *"double the size of `timestamps` array"* would be `2 * 5-floats = 10-floats` (not 25) -- or am I missing the *new math*?

Comment: A linked list has its special usecases, but I wouldn't recomment it in general. If you need fast indexed access and inserts/appends are relatively rare (which is often the case), implement your "*dynamic array*" using `malloc()`  and `realloc()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen or do a dry run and a single `malloc` (if dry run is possible). I usually prefer that over sequence of `reallocs`. Exponential growth of size is too much for me :)